# Using *ngFor with index, I am not getting the correct index from (onEditorCreated($event,i) ngx-Quill

Tags: angular, editor, quill

I have several posts that are displayed on screen using *ngFor. I am trying to target the css of the first two posts using Jquery.
Every post I create a quill-editor, I was hoping to use (onEditorCreated($event, i) in order to get the index of every post.
However even though {{i}} displays the right order (idPost0-idPost1-idPost2 etc.), when I console.log the i in the method onEditorCreatedPosted($event, i) the i shows 0,0,1,2,0 rather then 0,1,2,3,4,5.

Any idea what causes this behaviour?

```html
<div class ="smallwrapper2" id="{{'idPost'+i}}"  *ngFor="let key of publicPostContent; let i = index" > 
 {{i}}
<button class="textBoxDeveloper" name="textBoxDeveloper" (click)="selectPublicDeveloper(key._id, key.grade)">  
<quill-editor name="editor2" 
     [style]="{'width' : 'auto', 'font-size': '10px'}"
     [(ngModel)]="key.firstLineOfText"                (onEditorCreated)="this.onEditorCreatedPosted($event, i)"
     theme="bubble"  [modules]="{toolbar: false}"  >
     <div style="overflow:hidden"></div>
</quill-editor>     
</button>
```

Comment: Can we please see `onEditorCreatedPosted`, or is it just logging at the moment?

Comment: just logging at the moment

Comment: onEditorCreatedPosted starts with console.log(i) after that I have 20-30 of jquery lines that adapt the css. No loops. It is as if the onEditorCreated lacks behind on initialising, but never gets higher than I is 2 and gives i =0 twice. Even though {{i}} does count from 0 to 5.

Comment: 2 things to try: 1. drop the `this` on `this.OnEditorCreatedPosted`. 2. Instead of passing `i` to the event, maybe try just tracking it within the component as a private parameter and increment it at the start of each invocation.

Comment: Can you create a small example that shows this same behavior? I created a Plunker with what you have shown above but it does not have the same behavior: https://plnkr.co/edit/r4vsahgyIskwoS2vfip8?p=preview

Comment: @zze I tried both I think the problem is in using: import { QuillEditorComponent } from 'ngx-quill/src/quill-editor.component';
import { QuillModule } from 'ngx-quill'. When I update a private parameter indexCounter it mentions that the parameter changed when still working on the current one.

Comment: @Daniel W Strimpel, as per above the only difference to your plunker example is that I am using ngx-quill that allows me to use the <quill-editor> tag. I have a feeling that initialising the quill-editor works but that the onEditorCreated is a promise? So that this part is out of sync with the *ngFor loop? I will check it out later today, if this is the case. If you have any other solutions I would love to hear.

Comment: @zze I would like to put yours as the right answer, I just added a separate counter. My Jquery lines were targeting the first two posts but due to the wrong index I couldn't target those. I just wait till the first 3posts are created. so if (counter == 3) I then use the JQUERY lines. This solves the issue for me. As to why onEditorCreated is not giving the right indexes I think the onEditorCreated shows when the quill-editor is "ready" so it probably takes a while before it is is initalised, I am not sure, as this doesn't explain why the index gives 0,1,1,2,0.

Comment: @oudekaas Yeah, i'm not sure why it is logging such bizarre values. I am glad you got it working though!